# The number of pairs of integers $0\leq a \leq b < 2^N$ such that $ab \geq 2^N$

Tags: combinatorics

This seems  like a simple question but I am stuck on it.

> Is there a formula for the number of pairs of integers $0 \leq a \leq b < 2^N$ such that $ab \geq 2^N$?

For $N = 1,\dots,5$ the correct answers are  $0,3,19,96,437$.

Comment: Let's count. Fix a, how many b are there so that $ab\geq 2^n$?  b must satisfy that $b>2^n/a$. And so this number is equal to the sum

$\sum_{a=1}^{2^n}( 2^n-[2^n/a])$
Where $[2^n/a]$ is the integer part. Is this answers the question?

Comment: @yanko I was hoping for something that needed a sum over fewer than $2^N$ terms.  Also, $[] = \lfloor \rfloor$ in this case doesn't it because all the number are non-negative?

Comment: Approximately half of $(2^n-1)^2-n2^n ln 2$

Comment: @baharampuri I believe that is the kind of answer he was looking for, maybe you should write the answer with details.

Comment: @yanko added as an approximate solution; the formula I posted in the message is a little off I have corrected in the answer.

Comment: You might be interested in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.3369.pdf) which computes it in $O(2^{N/3})$ time.  This problem has been posted on [programming challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125158/counting-n-bit-integer-multiplication-overflows) where many values are given.

Answer (score 2):

Approximate solution: Let us look at the rectangle cornered at (1,1), $(1,2^N)$, $(2^N,2^N), (2^N,1)$ on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ plane. The integer points in this rectangle represent the set $\{(a,b): 1 \leq a,b \leq 2^n\}$. Out of these we have to count the integer points that satisfies $ab \geq 2^N$. Consider the right hand of the hyperbola $xy=2^N$. The integer points above the curve will be the set $\{(a,b)| 1 \leq a,b \leq 2^N,  ab \geq 2^N\}$. So half of these will be the number that is needed by the question.

An estimate could be made if we consider the region above the curve to the left of the line $y=x$ inside the rectangle. Which gives the integral:
$\int_{2^{N/2}}^{2^N} \int_{2^N/y}^{2^{N/2}} dxdy+ \int_{2^{N/2}}^{2^N} \int_{2^{N/2}}^{y} dxdy$ which simplifies to $2^{N-1}(2^N-1)-N2^{N-1}ln 2$.
For values of $N$, 3, 4, 5 we get approximately : 19, 97, 440..